# Schema design in avro and protobufs

Tags: schema, protocol-buffers, avro, parquet, protobuf-c

Currently a lot of data that we store are in the form of avro records , or serialized protobuf bytes. I want to see how can i design an efficient schema for my data to improve reading/parsing serializing speed by data pipelines.

For example consider the following case

```
Schema A : Column 1 : columnName : "eventType", type : string
           Column 2 : ColumnName : "Data", type : bytes

Schema B : Column 1 : columnName : "DataEventTypeA" : bytes
           Column 2 : columnName : "DataEventTypeB" : bytes
           Column 3 : columnName : "DataEventTypeC" : bytes
           ... so on basically flattening out Data column for each evenType
```

In my current setup i have multiple pipelines reading terabytes of Data in format schema A and then filter out a lot of that data based on eventType. Some eventTypes are pretty rare , so even though rare they still have to read terabytes of data and then filter out most of it
Even though schema B looks uglier, but because i know which particular column to read for a given eventype in a given pipeline I can create a projection schema in avro or proto (i.e having only fields that i want to read/deserialize) and then the parser will ignore the unknown columns and the data read  and deserialized is much less compared to the schema A. So a pipeline processing a rare event reads much less data instead of terabytes, although i agree my code will be slightly uglier of mapping eventtypes to schema and columnnames .

So are there any consideration that i should take into account for preferring wide columnar schema compared to narrow and long table given my usecase ? Or am i doing some anti design pattern. I know columnar storage would be nicer but because my events are all record format are there any obvious cons that I am missing ?